# Selectively mount network drives for non-root users

Tags: linux, fstab, multiple-users

How should one specify different mounts for different users?
The simplest use case is, that different users have their own dedicated storage space in a server (NFS or CIFS), what only they can access.

The traditional way to mount remote filesystems at boot is `fstab` in linux, but it contains system wide settings, so it can not be used to anything user specific.

Users not listed in the sudoers files can not use the mount command for drives which are not listed in the fstab. It just feels wrong to list all the possible mount combinations into the fstab, and also I am not sure how to resolve the issue, where multiple users has access to the very same shared drive.

What is the common wisdom regarding this? How should such a system be implemented? It seems like I have used the wrong search terms in my research.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux client software for both filesystems you mention (NFS or CIFS) supports multi-user mounts. The host can mount a location once using its machine credentials (which don't need to provide any access besides mounting), then each user accessing that location will be automatically recognized using their own credentials.

For NFS this happens automatically if you use `sec=krb5*` (Kerberos auth) or `sys` (UID-based authentication).

For SMB/CIFS it is activated using the `multiuser` mount option and primarily uses Kerberos as well. If not using Kerberos, the username and password for each user needs to be loaded using the `cifscreds` tool.